# Proving $\langle Ax, Ay\rangle = \langle A^{*}Ax, y\rangle$

Tags: inner-products

How do you prove that $\langle Ax, Ay\rangle  = \langle A^{*}Ax, y\rangle$ for an inner product space (IPS)? Lets just say $V = \mathbb{C^{n}}$ and $F = \mathbb{C}$ (Are there $F$ and $V$ where this isn't true?).

I assumed this would be a very simple proof using only the basic properties of the sesquilinear form and I am embarrassed that I can't get the details. Given an explicit definition for the IPS, e.g., the dot product, I can do this without issue, but for a general IPS, I can't figure out how to "move the matrix" so to speak.

Let $A_{i}$ denote the $i$th column of some matrix $A$, $x = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \alpha_{i}e_{i}$, and $y = \sum_{j=1}^{n} \beta_{j}e_{j}$. If I try this approach, I get something like

$$\langle Ax , By\rangle = \sum_{i} \overline{\beta_{i}}\langle Ax, A_{j}\rangle $$

which doesn't seem to go anywhere, however, I feel like expanding $x$ and $y$ into a linear combination of a standard basis is the only reasonable first step here.

Comment: It might have been a mistake to set $V = \mathbb R^n$, because the abstract case might be easier (there are fewer wrong directions to move in). What is your definition of $A^*$? Is $A$ not a linear transformation rather than a matrix?

Comment: @littleO I updated $V = \mathbb{C}^{n}$ prior to your comment if that matters. I was treating $A^{*}$ to be just the typical conjugate transpose of a matrix. I assumed it would be ok to fix $V$ because I figured this is all I need to hit everything in a finite-dimensional space up to an isomorphism.

Comment: @littleO I misread your comment and can no longer edit my other comment. Is the distinction between $A$ as a linear transformation or a matrix important? From my understanding, every linear transformation $T$ has a matrix representation so that $Tx = Ax$ so it doesn't really matter. I suspect I am misunderstanding something fundamental here based on your line of questioning.

Comment: I posted an answer to give some more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we are working in a general inner product space (over $\mathbb C$), then $A$ must be a linear transformation rather than a matrix. In this case, we can't define $A^*$ to be the conjugate transpose of $A$ (because $A$ is not a matrix). Usually we would define $A^*$ to be the unique linear transformation such that $\langle z, Ay\rangle = \langle A^*z, y \rangle$ for all $z, y$. From this definition, it follows immediately that $\langle Ax, Ay \rangle = \langle A^* A x,  y \rangle$ for all $x, y$.

If $V = \mathbb C^n$ and $A$ is a matrix and $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ is the standard inner product on $\mathbb C^n$, and $A^*$ is defined to be the conjugate transpose of the matrix $A$, then we can use the following argument:
\begin{align}
\langle Ax, Ay \rangle &= (Ay)^* Ax \\
&= y^* A^* Ax \\
&= \langle A^* Ax, y \rangle.
\end{align}

Comment: It is not clear to me how the first step is done in the case $V = \mathbb{C}^{n}$ and $A$ a matrix. I assume Kabo Murphy is suggesting I do the same thing. From my perspective, this only shows a specific case of a dot-product-like inner product. Is there no loss of generality from the first line $\langle Ax, Ay\rangle = (Ay)^{*}Ax$? Upon further reflection, I think I see why considering $A$ as a linear transformation is necessary if I choose something like $V = C[a,b]$.

Comment: @JessicaK I just edited the second half my post to clarify that, in this special case, $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ must be the standard inner product on $\mathbb C^n$. (That is, $\langle u, v \rangle = v^* u$.)

Comment: I will have to restudy the notion of adjoints, I did not realize $A^{*}$ was defined in this way, but it is clear now. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Verify that $\langle A^{*}e_i , e_j \rangle =\langle e_i , Ae_j \rangle $ for all $i,j$. Taking linear combinations conclude that $\langle A^{*}e_i , y \rangle =\langle e_i , Ay \rangle $ and  then conclude that $\langle A^{*}z , y \rangle =\langle z , Ay \rangle $ for all $z,x$. Now just put $z=Ax$.